# How to trigger Ajax forms machinery

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I'm working on ajaxifying a form which uses Hierarchical Select widget. I need to update a text field based on the value of HS and a couple of other fields. I want to use Drupal forms Ajax API. I followed the http://drupal.org/node/752056. Now the form is updated when user fills in the text fields. But I can't cope with HS.

I was told http://drupal.org/node/1630186 HS doesn't support regular Drupal #ajax mechanism. I can easily attach the handler to HS update event. So all I need now is to manually trigger Drupal Ajax machinery from my own handler. How it's best to be done?

I see there is a global Drupal.ajax object but can't figure out how to make use of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a really simple work around for this.
You can add a button or a hidden input field with an ajax callback and trigger this callback by jQuery.

So declare your button:

```
$form['my_button'] = array(
   '#type' => 'button',
   '#ajax' => array(
     'callback' => 'my_callback',
     'event' => 'hs_changed',
   ),
   // hide the button and set a unique id:
   '#prefix' => "<div style='display:none' id='my_ajax_button'>",
   '#suffix' => "</div>"
);
```

In your javascript you can then easily trigger the event with jQuery.trigger:

```
jQuery("#my_ajax_button input").trigger('hs_changed');
```

This will trigger your ajax callback.

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax

Comment: Wow, looks like it works :) Still trying to work out the details. I already have a couple of text field elements with #ajax attached. Can I reuse any of these? I tried to pass 'event' => array('click', 'hs_changed'). It doesn't work. The element stops reacting on clicks and triggered hs_changed events.

Comment: I don't know but I assume it isn't possible to attach two different ajax handlers for one element :(

Comment: Oh wait I guess I got you wrong. You can trigger the default click event. Try `jQuery(".another-button").mouseup()`

Comment: Yeah! It's 'blur' in my case though, and can easily be found out by inspectiong Drupal.ajax object. By the way, I couldn't attach the handler to custom form element.  Don't know why. Maybe because I'm altering an entity creation form, not building one from scratch.

Comment: Just to save someones time - Ghommey's answer is great, but for some reason, for me `jQuery(".another-button").mouseup()` part didn't work. However, `jQuery(".another-button").mousedown()` works.

Answer (score 2):

To piggy back on the answer above (I can't comment without 50 reputation...), you can attach a click handler with jQuery and trigger the namespaced event.

```
$form['my_button'] = array(
   '#type' => 'button',
   '#ajax' => array(
     'callback' => 'my_callback',
     'event' => 'hs_changed',
   )
);
```

And create a click handler with custom trigger.

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.buttonSubmit = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $('button', context).on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).trigger('hs_changed'); // Fires the AJAX submit
        // Add other button effects or changes below.
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```