# How to trigger ajax Form API action by js

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

In a custom form you can add an `#ajax` property, e.g.

```
$form['some_element'] = [
    '#type'  => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Foo',
    '#ajax'  => [ 'callback' => 'foo_callback',
                  'wrapper'  => 'some_dom_id' ],
];
```

On this element, drupal will attach a behaviour to `some_element`'s blur event. The behaviour submits the whole form, captures the response and uses it to replace the contents of `some_dom_id`.

I'm making a custom form element type and at a certain point (determined by non-Drupal js) I want to perform a Drupal AJAX update to the form without submitting it, just replacing a certain element; i.e. I want the 'normal' drupal behaviour, except I can't use the `#ajax` key to fire it.

**What js should I run to do a Drupal ajax-submit-form?**

### I've tried attaching #ajax directly onto my custom element

So I've tried adding the `#ajax` bit onto my form element in element_info, but this does not attach the behaviour to my custom form element. I didn't think it would - can't really see how Drupal would know how to. Perhaps there's a way I can implement this on my custom element?

Adding `#pre_render => [ 'ajax_pre_render_element' ]` to my `hook_element_info` seems to add the ajax behaviour, but I don't get the whole form submitted (just a long list of `ajax_html_id[]` entries and page state lists of css,js files and the theme token and the submitting element; the other inputs are not included?

### I've tried using a second 'normal' form element and hiding it

Yes this works, but it's a mess. Be a bit less messy if I could figure out how to add form elements within a custom form element implementation but that would be another question.

### EDIT

I can't remember the details of why I asked this question now! But reviewing it threw up [How to trigger Ajax forms machinery](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34372/how-to-trigger-ajax-forms-machinery?rq=1) which seemed to have the key info needed to get around this problem.

Comment: Anything wrong with `$('#form-id').submit();`?

Comment: Well as I understand it, that's going to submit the whole form in the normal non-ajaxy way. I think I've cracked it by adding `ajax_pre_render_element` to my custom element's `hook_element_info`...

Comment: Think about it - how could Drupal's ajax form submission functionality work in any other way than intercepting the submit event on the form (and subsequently preventing the default from running)...? If your code is outside Drupal, it might make sense to keep it outside Drupal and trigger the form submission from there

Comment: I appreciate your coaching! Um. there's dozens of ways to submit forms. But what you achieve with `.submit()` does not do the same as `$('#some-element-with-an-ajax-setting').trigger('blur')` (I'm using blur because it's usually blur, I'm using a custom event, too)? - there is no capture of response

Comment: Oh right, terminology breakdown then. By 'submit' I thought you literally meant 'submit' (as in HTML form submit), not 'perform a Drupal AJAX update to the form without submitting it' ;) (I didn't mean to sound condescending or anything with that "think about it" comment by the way, hope it didn't come across that way)

Comment: Not at all condescending, and no sarcasm, you are a Drupal genius, so I meant what I said, it is very much appreciated! Yeah, what you said is what I meant!